# Is this $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-2}}{n^2}$ absolutely convergent or conditionally convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, monotone-functions

I am trying to test convergence of the series $$S=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-2}}{n^2}$$

Method $1.$
We have $$\sum |a_n|=\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$$ which is convergent by $p$ series test. Thus the series $S$ is absolutely convergent.

Method $2.$ But when i use alternating series test, we have
$$S=a_1-a_2+a_3-....$$ where
$$a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$$ which satisfies
$a_1 \geq a_2 \geq a_3...$ and also $\lim_{n \to \infty} =0$.
So can't we say conditionally convergent too?

Comment: For conditional convergence to hold you require that $\lim_{m \to \infty} \sum_{n = 0}^{m} a_n$ exists, but $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n| = \infty$. Since your series is absolutely convergent, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n| < \infty$, hence it cannot be conditionally convergent

Comment: Ok got it thanku

Comment: Remember: the alternating series test only ever says that a series converges. It never tells us whether a series converges absolutely or conditionally (and it never tells us that a series diverges).